How to track core(pp0) power consumption using powercap framework (RAPL interface)
I'm trying to monitor the energy consumption of CPU core (pp0) using the powercap (RAPL) framework in Linux. I've tried on two machines, but I can only track the energy consumption for the package and DRAM.
These are the server informations:

Intel Xeon Silver 4116, Ubuntu 18.04, Linux 5.4.0-113-generic
Intel Xeon E5-2620 v4, Ubuntu 22.04, LInux 6.5.0-26-generic

Is there any other part that needs to be changed in the kernel module or kernel configuration? Also, I checked the Intel community and found information stating that it is included in intel-SST. I tried installing and running it, but I saw a message prompting to check if CONFIG_INTEL_SPEED_SELECT_INTERFACE is set.
